# why java don't have default value for arguments in method call

Tags: java

for example with C++ I can write

```
void func(int a=1,int b=2){...}
```

using Java I have to create several methods

Answer (score 6):

It wasn't a feature that the creators of Java thought was important enough to include.  Remember that Java was partially created as a reaction *against* the complexities of C++.